# export default is ignore? Empty output file

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm trying to bundle this with webpack:

```
import { initContainer } from "./embedTypes/container";
import { initPopup } from "./embedTypes/popup";
import { initBubble } from "./embedTypes/chat";

export default {
  initContainer,
  initPopup,
  initBubble,
};
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",

  entry: "./src/index.ts",

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "main.js",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2015",
    "target": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.ts"]
}
```

It outputs an empy `main.js` file and I don't understand why. Is this expected?

Comment: It depends on the content of your `embedTypes` files. If they only contain type definitions and no executable code, then yes, it's expected. webpack can only bundle executable code into js files. Everything `typescript` is ignored, as types dont' exist in plain JavaScript

Comment: These are real functions, there's some actual code. That's why I'm puzzled

Comment: Ok I just found the issue, it is the `module` prop in tsconfig that is invalid. I switched it to commonjs

Comment: Really? Looks fine to me, es6 and es2015 are [even the same version](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeScript-New-Handbook/reference/compiler-options/#module) if I'm not mistaken... Webpack actually advises against setting `module` to `commonjs`: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#loader